# Проблема с шаблонами django 4.0

Tags: python, django, шаблоны-проектирования

Я создал шаблон, все как в видео и документации, но мне выдает ошибку когда я запускаю сервер:

> raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(
> django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid templates
> library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load
> 'django.templates.i18n': No m odule named 'django.templates'

Вот проект [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import News


def index(request):
    news = News.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'news/index.html', {'news': news, 'title': 'News list'})
```

Код appps:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class NewsConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'news'
```

Код news/urls:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Вот все изменения в `settings`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'news.apps.NewsConfig',
'news',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'cumar.urls'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'cumar.wsgi.application'


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Не знаю, что еще может понадобится. Я уже и `INSTALLED_APPS` редактировал и `TEMPLATES`, все без толку. Заметил, что `TEMPLATES` изменили по сравнению с 3 версией. Может в этом дело?

Comment: Текст `django.templates.i18n` намекает, что возможно у вас в `settings.py` какой-то бред написан

Comment: @andreymal их редактировал только по видосу. Ничего от себя не добавлял. p.s добавил в вопрос все изменения settings

Comment: И строчки `django.templates.i18n` в settings.py нигде нету?

Comment: @andreymal нет. Единственное похожее 'BACKEND': 'django.templates.backends.django.DjangoTemplates', Спасибо что помогаете

Comment: `django.templates.backends` это тоже бред какой-то, существует только `django.template.backends`

Comment: @andreymal я ничего от себя не добавлял. Это по дефолту было. Попробовал исправить - не помогло

Comment: По дефолту команда `django-admin startproject` в актуальной версии Django 4.0.5 ничего подобного не добавляет (я только что проверил). Если вы что-то где-то сделали и уже сами забыли что и где — попробуйте создать проект заново с нуля и внимательно следите за тем где и что вы делаете

Comment: Ах да, ещё можно попробовать предположить, что вы воспользовались какой-то функцией массовой замены, например, слова `template` на слово `templates` и таким образом полностью сломали вообще всё, тогда точно нужно всё переустанавливать с нуля (впрочем, такое предположение не объясняет, откуда взялось загадочное `django.templates.i18n`, ведь даже модуля `django.template.i18n` в Django тоже не существует и никогда не существовало)

Answer (score 0):

Я просто создал новый проект, сделал все как в старом и проблема решилась. Не знаю что это было